# ¿Cómo consigo que se abra el explorador de archivos en vez de la versión anterior?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que comprima y descomprima archivos ".zip".

Cuando pulso el botón para abrir el explorador de archivos, me sale la versión antigua (no es la que quiero).
Yo quiero que salga el explorador de archivos moderno. Es decir, la misma interfaz que se usa cuando abres el explorador de archivos normal.
El código usado en el botón es el siguiente:

```
private void CompressButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Primero, selecciona la carpeta que deseas comprimir.\nLuego, la ubicación deseada.");
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        FolderBrowserDialog file = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hola");
        }

        if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hola");
        }

        if (zipName.Text == "")
        {
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(fbd.SelectedPath, file.SelectedPath + "/" + "archivoComprimido" + ".zip");
            MessageBox.Show("¡Su archivo fue comprimido con éxito!", "Operación completada");
        }
        else
        {
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(fbd.SelectedPath, file.SelectedPath + "/" + zipName.Text + ".zip");
            MessageBox.Show("¡Su archivo fue comprimido con éxito!", "Operación completada");
        }

    }
```

[image: Así es como me sale ahora]

Este es código que uso para llamar al explorador de archivos :

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog(); 
FolderBrowserDialog file = new FolderBrowserDialog(); 
if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { 
    Console.WriteLine("Hola"); 
} 
if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { 
    Console.WriteLine("Hola"); 
}
```

Comment: que boton pulsas para que abra el explorador de archivo ? es algo que tu programas, si es asi que codigo implementas

Comment: Sí, es algo que programo. Este es el código.
`FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            FolderBrowserDialog file = new FolderBrowserDialog();

            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hola");
            }

            if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hola");
            }`

Comment: He agregado tu codigo a la pregunta, para cualquier añadido a tu pregunta pulsa en [edit] para que todos los usuarios esten actualizados con lo que has intentado / buscado :)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias @Capt.Teach!

Comment: Pero quieres seleccionar una carpeta o archivos?

Comment: Primero quiero seleccionar una carpeta (la carpeta que se comprimirá), y luego quiero obtener la carpeta dónde se guardará el .zip.

Comment: pero el diseño del FolderBrowserDialog  es estandar, porque dices que ese que nos muestras en la imagen es una version antigua? cual seria la moderna? tienes alguna imagen

Comment: No sé como explicarlo, me refería a esto: https://imgur.com/M4Fjiej

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Encontré la solución. 
Para todos los que quieran usar un Open File Dialog para buscar carpetas, puedes descargarse [este paquete](https://github.com/jamie-pate/KeepSync/blob/master/contrib/Windows%20API%20Code%20Pack%201.1.zip). Luego, deben añadir estos dos archivos a las referencias:

- Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll
- Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll

[Este artículo lo explica](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2018/11/use-a-standard-windows-dialog-to-let-the-user-select-folders-in-c/)

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/205338)

Comment: Oh, ya veo. Gracias. Ahora añado lo importante.